# from list of tuples to array with the 2nd row become the header

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, matrix

from list of tuples to array with the 2nd row become the header to print it to a csv file.

This is my data set for buss trips between cities
original list

```
L= [ 
("Seattle WA US","Seattle WA US","56"),
("Seattle WA US","North Bend WA US","1"),
("Seattle WA US","Candelaria 137 PR","2"),
("Seattle WA US","La Cienega NM US","2"),
("Seattle WA US","Thousand Palms CA US","1"),
("Oakhurst CA US","Thousand Palms CA US","10")
]
```

when I print it to csv I get using :

```
ifile  = open('test.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
ofile  = open('ttest.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='  ', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer.writerow(["departure","destination", "trips_count"])
for row in L:
    writer.writerow(list(row))
```

I get:

```
departure       destination             trips_count
Seattle WA US   Seattle WA US           56
Seattle WA US   North Bend WA US        1
Seattle WA US   Candelaria 137 PR       2
Seattle WA US   La Cienega NM US        2
Seattle WA US   Thousand Palms CA US    1
Oakhurst CA US  Thousand Palms CA US    10
```

How can I change it to this format?

```
                    Seattle WA US   North Bend WA US    Candelaria 137 PR   La Cienega NM US    Thousand Palms CA US
Seattle WA US       56              1                   2                   2                   1
Oakhurst CA US      0               0                   0                   0                   10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

L= [ 
("Seattle WA US","Seattle WA US","56"),
("Seattle WA US","North Bend WA US","1"),
("Seattle WA US","Candelaria 137 PR","2"),
("Seattle WA US","La Cienega NM US","2"),
("Seattle WA US","Thousand Palms CA US","1"),
("Oakhurst CA US","Thousand Palms CA US","2")
]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['departure', 'destination', 'trips_count'])
df = df.pivot(index='departure', columns='destination').fillna(0)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

**Output:**

```
In [17]: df = df.pivot(index='departure', columns='destination').fillna(0)

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
                     trips_count                                    \
destination    Candelaria 137 PR La Cienega NM US North Bend WA US   
departure                                                            
Oakhurst CA US                 0                0                0   
Seattle WA US                  2                2                1   


destination    Seattle WA US Thousand Palms CA US  
departure                                          
Oakhurst CA US             0                    2  
Seattle WA US             56                    1
```

More information about [pandas reshaping and pivot table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)

Comment: Like charm! Thank you @MaThMaX .

Comment: @mongotop, Glad it helps! More information about [pandas reshaping and pivot table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)

Comment: very helpful indeed! thank you again! I added your link to your answer to be easy to find for future seekers :)